# WPF Bind Canvas.Left/Canvas.Top to Point DependencyProperty, Use PointAnimation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

Please consider the following simplified example which illustrates my problem:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Width="500" Height="500"
        Title="Click anywhere to animate the movement of the blue thingy...">
    <Canvas 
        x:Name="canvas" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
        Background="AntiqueWhite"  
        MouseDown="canvas_MouseDown" />
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.canvas.Children.Add(new Thingy());
        }

        private void canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var thingy = (Thingy)this.canvas.Children[0];

            var from = new Point(0.0, 0.0);

            var to = new Point(
                canvas.ActualWidth  - thingy.ActualWidth, 
                canvas.ActualHeight - thingy.ActualHeight
            );

            var locAnim = new PointAnimation(
                from, 
                to, 
                new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
            );

            locAnim.Completed += (s, a) =>
            {
                // Only at this line does the thingy move to the 
                // correct position...
                thingy.Location = to;
            };

            thingy.Location = from;
            thingy.BeginAnimation(Thingy.LocationProperty, locAnim);
        }
    }
}
```

Thingy.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.Thingy"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Width="50" Height="50" Background="Blue" />
```

Thingy.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class Thingy : UserControl
    {
        public static DependencyProperty LocationProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Location", 
                typeof(Point), 
                typeof(Thingy)
            );

        public Thingy()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Canvas.SetLeft(this, 0.0);
            Canvas.SetTop(this, 0.0);

            var xBind = new Binding();
            xBind.Source = this;
            xBind.Path = new PropertyPath(Canvas.LeftProperty);
            xBind.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

            var yBind = new Binding();
            yBind.Source = this;
            yBind.Path = new PropertyPath(Canvas.TopProperty);
            yBind.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

            var locBind = new MultiBinding();
            locBind.Converter = new PointConverter();
            locBind.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            locBind.Bindings.Add(xBind);
            locBind.Bindings.Add(yBind);
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(
                this, 
                Thingy.LocationProperty, 
                locBind
            );
        }

        public Point Location
        {
            get
            {
                return (Point)this.GetValue(LocationProperty);
            }

            set
            {
                this.SetValue(LocationProperty, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PointConverter.cs

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class PointConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] v, Type t, object p, CultureInfo c)
        {
            return new Point((double)v[0], (double)v[1]);
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object v, Type[] t, object p, CultureInfo c)
        {
            return new object[] { ((Point)v).X, ((Point)v).Y };
        }
    }
}
```

The goals here are:

1. Use the `LocationProperty` to manipulate and access the `Canvas.LeftProperty` and `Canvas.TopProperty` values.
2. Animate said `LocationProperty` with the `PointAnimation` class.

Goal #1 appears to be working correctly, it's only when trying to animate the `LocationProperty` does it not behave as expected.

By "expected" I mean the instance of `Thingy` should move as the animation progresses.

I am able to accomplish this using two instances of the `DoubleAnimation` class.

If the problem is that `Point` is a value type, then I suspect that I could define my own `Point` type and my own `AnimationTimeline`. This is not what I wish to do. This is part of a much larger project and the `LocationProperty` will be used for other things.

And to be honest, the bottom line is that it seems to me this should just work, can you tell me:

1. Why it does not?
2. If there is a solution to the problem as defined?

I'll also mention that I'm targeting .Net Framework 4.5 for this project.

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if this would help, but have you tried attaching a TranslateTransform to Thingy and binding/animating the transformation instead of Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top? At minimum it would perform a lot better.

Comment: When you say "I am able to accomplish this using two instances of the DoubleAnimation class." what do you mean? What properties are you animating in that case?

Comment: @PeterMoore Thanks for the TranslateTransform idea, I'll definitely look into that. To answer your question, I used the DoubleAnimations on Canvas.Left/Top.

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense. See my updated answer for why your original approach didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the simplest code to animate something.

- it leverages the dependency property callback
- does not use a binding
- does not use a converter
- does not use a storyboard

Main window:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainWindow_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var x = Canvas.GetLeft(Control1);
            var y = Canvas.GetTop(Control1);
            x = double.IsNaN(x) ? 0 : x;
            y = double.IsNaN(y) ? 0 : y;
            var point1 = new Point(x, y);
            var point2 = e.GetPosition(this);
            var animation = new PointAnimation(point1, point2, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
            animation.EasingFunction = new CubicEase();
            Control1.BeginAnimation(UserControl1.LocationProperty, animation);
        }
    }
}
```

Main window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" MouseDown="MainWindow_OnMouseDown">
    <Canvas>
        <local:UserControl1 Background="Red" Height="100" Width="100" x:Name="Control1" />
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Control:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class UserControl1
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LocationProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Location", typeof(Point), typeof(UserControl1), new UIPropertyMetadata(default(Point), OnLocationChanged));

        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Point Location
        {
            get { return (Point) GetValue(LocationProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LocationProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void OnLocationChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var control1 = (UserControl1) d;
            var value = (Point) e.NewValue;
            Canvas.SetLeft(control1, value.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(control1, value.Y);
        }
    }
}
```

Control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

</UserControl>
```

**TODO:** adjust the code to your needs :)

**EDIT: A trivial two-way binding that listens to `Canvas.[Left|Top]Property`:**

(to be enhanced)

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class UserControl1
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LocationProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Location", typeof(Point), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(default(Point), OnLocationChanged));

        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(Canvas.LeftProperty, typeof(Canvas))
                .AddValueChanged(this, OnLeftChanged);
            DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(Canvas.TopProperty, typeof(Canvas))
                .AddValueChanged(this, OnTopChanged);
        }

        public Point Location
        {
            get { return (Point) GetValue(LocationProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LocationProperty, value); }
        }

        private void OnLeftChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            var left = Canvas.GetLeft(this);
            Location = new Point(left, Location.Y);
        }

        private void OnTopChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var top = Canvas.GetTop(this);
            Location = new Point(Location.X, top);
        }

        private static void OnLocationChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var control1 = (UserControl1) d;
            var value = (Point) e.NewValue;
            Canvas.SetLeft(control1, value.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(control1, value.Y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! it was the OnLocationChanged callback I was lacking... Side note, the reason I'm using binding/converter is because I want there to always be a two way connection between Location.X/Y and Canvas.Left/Top. I'll implement the callback and adjust accordingly. Thanks so much!

Comment: Look at my edit, I've added a trivial way to reflect changes by listening to changes in `Canvas` property (did not thoroughly check but it does work). Note that WPF is smart enough to not endlessly update the property.

Answer (score 1):

I like Aybe's answer but it doesn't address why the original code doesn't work. I ran your code and tried some alternatives and it appears what is happening is that the binding converter is being ignored during the animation. If you set a breakpoint in the converter methods, or do a Debug.WriteLine, either way you can see that the converter is not getting invoked throughout the animation, but rather only when the property is explicitly set in your code.

Digging deeper, the problem is in the way you're setting up the `Thingy` bindings. The binding **source** property should be `Thingy.Location` while the  **target** properties should be `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top`. You have it backwards though - you're making `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` the source properties and `Thingy.Location` the target property. You would think making it a two-way binding would make it work (and it does, when you explicitly set the `Thingy.Location` property), but it appears that the Two-Way binding aspect is ignored for animations.

One solution is not to use a multi-binding here. Multi-binding is really for when one property is being sourced by multiple properties or conditions. Here, you have multiple properties (`Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top`) that you want to source with a single property - `Thingy.Location`. So, in the `Thingy` constructor:

```
    var xBind = new Binding();
    xBind.Source = this;
    xBind.Path = new PropertyPath(Thingy.LocationProperty);
    xBind.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
    xBind.Converter = new PointToDoubleConverter();
    xBind.ConverterParameter = false;
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, Canvas.LeftProperty, xBind);                

    var yBind = new Binding();
    yBind.Source = this;
    yBind.Path = new PropertyPath(Thingy.LocationProperty);
    yBind.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
    yBind.Converter = new PointToDoubleConverter();
    yBind.ConverterParameter = true;
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, Canvas.TopProperty, yBind);
```

The other difference is the binding converter. Rather than take two `doubles` and give you a `Point`, we need a converter that takes a `Point` and extracts the `double` used for the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties (and I'm using the `ConverterParameter` to specify which one is desired). So:

```
public class PointToDoubleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var pt = (Point)value;
        bool isY = (bool)parameter;
        return isY ? pt.Y : pt.X;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

This makes the animation work while still using bindings and converters. The only drawback here is that the bindings between the `Canvas` properties and `Thingy.Location` are necessarily one-way because there's no way to convert `Canvas.Left` or `Canvas.Top` alone back to a full `Point`. In other words if you subsequently change `Canvas.Left` or `Canvas.Top`, `Thingy.Location` won't update. (This is true of any binding-less solution as well of course).

However, if you do go back to your original multi-binding version, and just add the code to the `Location` property change handler to update `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top`, you can have your cake and eat it too. They wouldn't need to be `TwoWay` bindings at that point because you're taking care of updating `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` in the property change handler for `Location`. Basically all the actual binding is then doing is making sure `Location` updates when `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` do.

In any event, the mystery is solved as to why your original approach didn't work. When setting up complex bindings it's crucial to correctly identify the source and the targets; `TwoWay` bindings are not a catch-all for all cases, notably, animations.